# VBA increment row number by using a variable

Tags: vba, excel

I have got this statement of code

```
Range("A"&Number :"W" & Number).Copy
```

Where Number is a digit representing the row. But this particular range doesn't seem to work well. I get a compile error and i don't know how to fix the Range to include a variable that increments the row number

Any help on that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Range("A" & Number & ":W" & Number).Copy
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way

```
Const COLW As Long = 23

Cells(Number,1).Resize(1,COLW).Copy
```